# Hidrostatics - In a U shape tube, water is added to a fluid with density 1,4. What is the distance from the top of the water to the top of the tube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

I came across this exercise, and I can't seem to reach a proper answer. I translated the exercise from another language to english, so please, if something isn't clear, let me know!

[image]

My attempt to solve it goes as follows:

`Vw = 320cm3 = 3,2×10^−4 m3

A=16cm2 = 1,6×10^−3 m2`
Since the tubes are cilinders,
`V = A×hw

3,2×10−4 = 1,6×10^−3 × hw

0,2 m = hw`

So, we now know that the added water column measures 0, 2 m, or 20 cm. Now, I tried to figure out what was the necessary height of the red liquid, in column B, that balanced out the pressure that the added water exerts:

[image]

Following what I’m thinking, I thought that since column B increased 14,285 cm in size, that the water in column A dropped these 14,285 cm as well, and so the distance would be 20 − 14, 285 = 5, 72, but... the answer is 7,14. Where is my line of thought failing?

Any help is much appreciated.